# Servlet get json array with getParameter

Tags: java, json, servlets

I recieve to servlet an array like this with `request.getParameter("jsondata");`

```
jsondata {"rows":{"1":["2","0","0"],"2":["0","0","0"],"3":["0","0","0"]},"columns":{"1":["2","0","0"],"2":["0","0","0"],"3":["0","0","0"]}}
```

And I will send back the data like this:

```
response.setContentType("application/json");
        PrintWriter out =response.getWriter();

        String jsonStr =  "{\"rows\": \""+rowsResult +"\",\"columns\":\""+columnsResult+"\"}";
        out.print(jsonStr);
        out.flush();
```

How can I calculate the sum of rows and columns?

Comment: Use a JSON parser to convert the JSON into a Java data structure you can use.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis How should I do it? Can you make me an example please? :/

Answer (score 0):

Update based on comment

**input objects**

```
public class JsonInput {

    private ArrayData rows;
    private ArrayData columns;

    public ArrayData getRows() {
        return rows;
    }

    public void setRows(ArrayData rows) {
        this.rows = rows;
    }

    public ArrayData getColumns() {
        return columns;
    }

    public void setColumns(ArrayData columns) {
        this.columns = columns;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
    return "JsonInput [rows=" + rows + ", columns=" + columns + "]";
    }
}

import java.util.List;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;


public class ArrayData {

    @SerializedName("1")
    private List<Integer> dataOne;
    @SerializedName("2")
    private List<Integer> dataTwo;
    @SerializedName("3")
    private List<Integer> dataThree;

    public List<Integer> getDataOne() {
        return dataOne;
    }
    public void setDataOne(List<Integer> dataOne) {
        this.dataOne = dataOne;
    }
    public List<Integer> getDataTwo() {
        return dataTwo;
    }
    public void setDataTwo(List<Integer> dataTwo) {
        this.dataTwo = dataTwo;
    }
    public List<Integer> getDataThree() {
        return dataThree;
    }
    public void setDataThree(List<Integer> dataThree) {
        this.dataThree = dataThree;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ArrayData [dataOne=" + dataOne + ", dataTwo=" + dataTwo
                + ", dataThree=" + dataThree + "]";
    }
}
```

**output objects**

```
public class JsonOutput {

    private SumObj rows;
    private SumObj columns;

    public SumObj getRows() {
        return rows;
    }

    public void setRows(SumObj rows) {
        this.rows = rows;
    }

    public SumObj getColumns() {
        return columns;
    }

    public void setColumns(SumObj columns) {
        this.columns = columns;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
    return "JsonOutput [rows=" + rows + ", columns=" + columns + "]";
    }
}


import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;


public class SumObj {

    @SerializedName("1")
    private Integer dataOne;
    @SerializedName("2")
    private Integer dataTwo;
    @SerializedName("3")
    private Integer dataThree;

    public Integer getDataOne() {
        return dataOne;
    }
    public void setDataOne(Integer dataOne) {
        this.dataOne = dataOne;
    }
    public Integer getDataTwo() {
        return dataTwo;
    }
    public void setDataTwo(Integer dataTwo) {
        this.dataTwo = dataTwo;
    }
    public Integer getDataThree() {
        return dataThree;
    }
    public void setDataThree(Integer dataThree) {
        this.dataThree = dataThree;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "SumObj [dataOne=" + dataOne + ", dataTwo=" + dataTwo
                + ", dataThree=" + dataThree + "]";
    }
}
```

**The parser**

```
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

public class Sample {
    //{"rows":{"1":["2","0","0"],"2":["0","0","0"],"3":["0","0","0"]},"columns":{"1":["2","0","0"],"2":["0","0","0"],"3":["0","0","0"]}}
    private static final String inputJson = "{\"rows\":{\"1\":[\"2\",\"0\",\"0\"],\"2\":[\"0\",\"0\",\"0\"],\"3\":[\"0\",\"0\",\"0\"]},\"columns\":{\"1\":[\"2\",\"0\",\"0\"],\"2\":[\"0\",\"0\",\"0\"],\"3\":[\"0\",\"0\",\"0\"]}}";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Type listType = new TypeToken<JsonInput>() {}.getType();
    JsonInput input = gson.fromJson(inputJson, listType);

    JsonOutput response = new JsonOutput();
    response.setRows(getSumObject(input.getRows()));
    response.setColumns(getSumObject(input.getColumns()));

    listType = new TypeToken<JsonOutput>() {}.getType();
    String output = gson.toJson(response, listType);
    System.out.println(output);
    }

    private static SumObj getSumObject(ArrayData input) {
        SumObj obj = new SumObj();

        obj.setDataOne(getSum(input.getDataOne()));
        obj.setDataTwo(getSum(input.getDataTwo()));
        obj.setDataThree(getSum(input.getDataThree()));

        return obj;
    }

    private static Integer getSum(List<Integer> data) {
        int sum = 0;

        for(Integer i : data){
            sum += i;
        }

        return sum;
    }
}
```

Comment: But I get the json from a post of jquery. What can I do?

Comment: So then the json should be same always. That means rows should be always 3.. When you say something within {} its an object say "rows":{"1":["2","0","0"],"2":["0","0","0"],"3":["0","0","0"]} means rows is an object with 3 fields and each fields is an object of type {"1":["2","0","0"]}. So if you want to follow the exact structure you should create appropriate objects. To make things easy converted that to array and shown you an example.

Comment: If you didn't understand this give me the actual json string and just explain what did you meant by sum of rows and columns? For eg: does sum of row means sum of the keys "1", "2" & "3" or sum of the values within each key [2,0,0] or sum of value of all three keys? If so i can modify my program to match you requirement.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation,yes I have a table in html with input texts when I put the values, I do a post and I send it by json. The thing that I want to do is: when I recieve for example 1":["2","3","0"] sum = 5 do it for rows and for columns.